# How can I get the current machine's AWS credentials?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance with an Instance Profile. I need to pass those credentials to another service so it can make a request on to another service. In Python, I can do this:

```
session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()
```

After which I can use

```
credentials.access_key
credentials.secret_key
credentials.token
```

I'm looking for a way to do the same thing in PHP.

Comment: What about the [getCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.AwsClient.html#_getCredentials) method of the aws client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work, based on the comments.

```
<?

require "./vendor/autoload.php";

$client = new Aws\Sts\StsClient(array("region" => "us-east-1", "version" => "latest"));
$creds = $client->getCredentials()->wait();

echo $creds->getAccessKeyId();
echo $creds->getSecretKey();
echo $creds->getSecurityToken();

?>
```

Comment: Works.  Sheesh, I was focused on something session based, like `$creds = $client->getSessionToken();`